# How to update each div element with Ajax function using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I am new to JQuery and I have an Ajax function to update the `select` options. The Ajax is working fine on my first Div. But when I clone the div and run the Ajax call it again update the first Div element only not the element of cloned one. I new to closet... etc. Please help me so when I call the Ajax it will update the cloned div(current div) element.

this is my ajax function:

```
function acct_dbox()  {
   {#var that = $(this)#}
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/waccounts/getaccounts",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            {#'acctlevel': $(this).val(),#}
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
        },
        success: function (data) {
           $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                if (item.length > 0){
              console.log('test', item[0].AcctCode);
              console.log('test', item[0].AcctName);
              {#$("#id_accountcode  option").remove();#}
              $.each(item, function(index1, item1) {
                console.log(item1.id);
                console.log(item1.AcctCode);
                console.log(item1.AcctName);
                $("#id_accountcode").append($('<option/>',{

                {#$("#id_accountcode").append($('<option/>', {#}
                  value: item1.AcctCode,
                  text: item1.AcctName

            }));
  })

 $( document ).ready(function() {
    acct_dbox();
    var original_external_int_div = document.getElementById('account_list'); 
    //Div to Clone
    var clone = original_external_int_div.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    original_external_int_div.parentNode.append(clone);

    acct_dbox();  # (it is updating the first div again - not cloned one)

});
```

My html is:

```
 {% extends 'wstore_base_generic.html' %}

 {% block content %}
 <form action="" method="post" class="w-auto" id="new_trans_form" 
 xmlns:width="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<div class="row mt-1 mb-4" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
            <div class="headerctr">
                <h3>JV</h3>
                <!-- <div> -->
                <!-- <h3 > -->

                <!-- </h3> -->
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div 38rem class="row style= width:18">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Transaction Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name=" 
 {{form.fh_dt.name}}" value="{{current_date}}"
                            readonly>
                        {% if form.fh_dt.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.fh_dt.errors  %}
                        <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm" >
                        <label>Transaction Number</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name=" 
 {{form.fh_no.name}}"
                            value="{{transaction_number}}" readonly>
                        {% if form.fh_no.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.fh_no.errors  %}
                        <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">

                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name=" 
   {{form.fh_type.name}}" required readonly
                            value="JV">
                        {% if form.fh_type.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.fh_type.errors  %}
                        <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}

                        <label>Transaction Ref.</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name=" 
 {{form.fh_ref.name}}" required
                            value="Ref.">
                        {% if form.fh_ref.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.fh_ref.errors  %}
                        <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-0">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Transaction Code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name=" 
 {{form.fh_code.name}}" required readonly
                            value="JV">
                        {% if form.fh_code.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.fh_code.errors  %}
                        <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Transaction Detail</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name=" 
 {{form.fh_detail.name}}" required
                            value="Detail">
                        {% if form.fh_detail.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.fh_detail.errors  %}
                        <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Transaction UserCode</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name=" 
 {{form.fh_user_code.name}}" required
                            value="{% if form.fh_user_code.value %} 
  {{form.fh_user_code.value}}{% else %}{{request.user.username}}{% endif %}">
                        {% if form.fh_user_code.errors %}
                        {% for error in fh_user_code.errors  %}
                        <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-0">
        <div class="card shadow">
            <div class="card-header text-center">
                <h3 class="headerctr">
                    Item Details
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th  class = "text-danger">Account</th>
                            <th  class = "text-danger">Debits</th>
                            <th class="text-success">Credits</th>
                            <th  class = "text-warning">Description</th>
                            <th  class = "text-warning">Tax</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="account_list" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select name="acct_code" class="form-control 
   fh_code" id="id_accountcode">
                                         <option  value="SELECT" 
  selected="selected">---SELECT---</option>
                                         required></select>
                            </td>
                             <td>
                                <input type="text" name="acct_name" 
   class="form-control fh_name"
                                    placeholder="Acct Code" readonly>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               <input type="number" name="acct_debit" 
class="form-control fh_debit"
                                    placeholder=" " >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control 
    fh_credit" name="acct_credit"
                                    placeholder=" ">
                            </td>
                            <td>                                    
                                <input type="text" class="form-control 
   fh_detail" placeholder="Description"
                               name="acct_descript"     >
                            </td>
                             <td>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control 
  fh_tax" name="acct_tax"
                                    placeholder=" ">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" id="btnadd" 
 class="btn add_new_row" title="Add">
                                        <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn 
 delete_row" title="Delete">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>              
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>                                 
                            <td class = "text-success">Total Quantity: 
 <strong id="final_quantity">0</strong></td>
                            <td></td>                                                 
                            <td class = "text-success"> Total Price: <strong 
 id="final_price">0</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a  href="{% url 'transactions' transtype='INV' 
 posted='ALL' %}"  class="btn btn-info mr-2" >Cancel</a>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit_form" 
  name="save_next" value="Save&Print">&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: show html as well.

Comment: html is added in my question. Thanks.

Comment: You are cloning tbody ? Also , there will mutliple elements with same ids that's why only first one works .

Comment: See if this `$("table tbody:last select[name=acct_code]").append(youroptionsto appendhere)` works. Also , please remove all duplicate ids.

Comment: it was updating the last select only; I made a change like: $("table tbody select[name=acct_code]").append($('<option/>',{...        removing --last-- it update all rows.  please give corrected answer to mark 'ANSWER' Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 {#$("#id_accountcode").append($('<option/>', {#}
              value: item1.AcctCode,
              text: item1.AcctName
```

I made a change like:

```
 $("table tbody select[name=acct_code]").append($('<option/>',
```

the all div selects get updated with option  -Thanks to swathi.